# In Project Reactor, what is a "target" Mono/Flux?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

eg, the [Mono#transform method](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#transform-java.util.function.Function-) docs say the following:

> Transform this Mono in order to generate a **target Mono**

What does "target Mono" mean?

Answer (score 3):

It's not always consistent, but in the reactor documentation, the use of "target" generally signals that the *type* of the publisher potentially changes. In the case of `transform()` I'm pretty sure it's actually meant to say "target type", as the docs for both `transformDeferred()` and `transformDeferredContextual()` do - there's no reason why it would be any different from the standard `transform()` operator.

Don't overthink it though - it's simply the `Mono` that's been transformed by the method. "Target" doesn't have any special meaning in a reactive context that you need to be aware of.